# Inline a dictionary to a dictionary

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I need to set a header that contain some json. I have tried with the following. Is it possible and can you do it? Note I am using `SwiftyJSON`, hence the `JSON(jsonVar). rawString()`

From SwiftyJSON:

> ```
> public func rawString(encoding: UInt = NSUTF8StringEncoding, options opt: NSJSONWritingOptions = .PrettyPrinted) -> String? {
>     switch self.type {
>     case .Array, .Dictionary:
>         do {
>             let data = try self.rawData(options: opt)
>             return NSString(data: data, encoding: encoding) as? String
>         } catch _ {
>             return nil
>         }
>     case .String:
>         return self.rawString
>     case .Number:
>         return self.rawNumber.stringValue
>     case .Bool:
>         return self.rawNumber.boolValue.description
>     case .Null:
>         return "null"
>     default:
>         return nil
>     }
> }
> ```

```
let addthis = [
    "foo": [1,2,3],
    "bar": [
        "baz": "qux"
    ]
]


    let headers = [
        //    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "addthis":" \(JSON(addthis).rawString()) "
    ]
```

I get this on the http server:

```
Optional("{\n  \"foo\" : [\n    1,\n    2,\n    3\n  ],\n  \"bar\" : {\n    \"baz\" : \"qux\"\n  }\n}")
```

Comment: is the question why "one":"1" is missing?

Comment: Nope, the problem is that I get: Optional("{\n  \"foo\" : [\n    1,\n    2,\n    3\n  ],\n  \"bar\" : {\n    \"baz\" : \"qux\"\n  }\n}") Where it should be a json?

Comment: @ChrisG. JSON **is** a string!

Comment: what do you expect there ?

Comment: I did not  expect Optional and all the backslashes

Answer (score 0):

```
let headers = [
    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "addthis": JSON(addthis).rawString()!
]
```

be careful! check first if .rawString is valid String first!
...

```
if let json = JSON(addthis).rawString() {
    let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "addthis": json
    ]
}
```

... or if an empty String is acceptable

```
let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "addthis": JSON(addthis).rawString() ?? ""
    ]
```

...

```
var a: String? = "alfa"
print(a, a.dynamicType) // Optional("alfa") Optional<String>
let b = a ?? ""
print(b, b.dynamicType) // alfa String
```

... is giving this backslash trouble ....
 " as part of String MUST be escaped like "\"" .

Comment: Nope, still getting Optional("{\n  \"foo\" : [\n    1,\n    2,\n    3\n  ],\n  \"bar\" : {\n    \"baz\" : \"qux\"\n  }\n}")

Comment: If you try this in playground you will se print(headers) is giving this backslash trouble....

Comment: I am not able to do it, because I don't know nothing about your JSON(...).rawString() function.

Comment: i guess, it returns Optional<String> , doesn't it?

Comment: Updated the question to include the SwiftyJSON function

Comment: Maybe it is the .PrettyPrinted in NSUTF8StringEncoding. I will just test to see.

Comment: pretty, or not. it has nothing with your question. print 'my' third version of headers and show me the result

Comment: "["Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==", "addthis": "{\\n  \\"foo\\" : [\\n    1,\\n    2,\\n    3\\n  ],\\n  \\"bar\\" : {\\n    \\"baz\\" : \\"qux\\"\\n  }\\n}", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]\n"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95724/discussion-between-user3441734-and-chris-g).

Answer (score 0):

I believe only thing you can do is:

```
 let jsonString = removeUnexpectedCharactersFromJSONString(YOURJSON.rawString()!)
```

I wrote simple function:

```
func removeUnexpectedCharactersFromJSONString(jsonString: String) -> String {
    var newStr = jsonString
    newStr = newStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "")
    newStr = newStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    newStr = newStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\t", withString: "")
    return newStr
}
```

[image]